# Problemas al pasar Wordpress de local a servidor

Tags: wordpress

Recientemente termine un curso online de WordPress y Woocommerce que hice en local en mi pc. Ahora quiero subir a internet los archivos de que tengo en local a un sitio que tengo en un servidor para ver si todo va bien online también. Resumo un poco la experiencia:
1. Subí los archivos al servidor sin problema
2. Al entrar en la direccion de mi pagina me sale un mensaje de "Error establishing a database connection".
3. Reviso el wp-config.php para cambiar los datos de contraseña, nombre de bd, etc.
4. Al entrar en la direccion de nuevo me sale el asistente de WordPress para empezar a instalar el idioma, etc.

Mi pregunta es: ¿no deberia aparecer instalado ya? Supongo que debe crear las bd en el servidor que tengo online por eso sale de nuevo esta instalación ¿es asi? Y... ¿puedo aprovechar algo de lo que hice en local para lo que voy a instalar en el servidor? 
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que la importacion a tu hosting de wordpress sea correcta, debes seguir los siguientes pasos.

1. Sube la raiz completa de wordpress por ftp a tu servidor.
2. Crea una copia de tu base de datos local e importala a la base de datos de tu hosting.

   3. en la base de datos, debes ir a wp-options y cambiar siteurl y el blogname por la url de tu sitio online.

Con eso deberia de bastar, pero si te sigue fallando, tienes que ir a .htacces y dejarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Eso es lo que debes de tener en cuenta, y claro, que los datos en wp_config esten bien

Comment: Ay, ya importe la base de datos al servidor...pero sin cambiar las rutas a la base de datos de localhost a la nueva web. ¿Puedo hacer el cambio y volverlo a importar? ¿habria algun problema? Si hay problema ¿como puedo hacer?

Comment: 0
votar en contra
Puedes hacerlo ahora. Cambia las rutas y listo.

Comment: Perfecto, funcionó. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes copiar la base de datos de tu local usando phpadmin, la guardas en mysql y en el panel de tu servidor online creas la base, un usuario para la base e importas el archivo mysql que obtuviste anteriormente y debería funcionar. Te pongo un link para que revises paso a paso.

https://www.gianoliveira.com/wordpress-de-local-a-remoto.html

Comment: No me funciona. He seguido los pasos fielmente de este enlace que proporcionas. Todos, excepto uno: la copia de archivos via ftp de local a servidor la hice al principio y no al final como se dice en el tutorial. ¿Es posible que eso este afectando?

Comment: No debe afectar, ¿Qué error te marca el sitio?

Comment: El error es "Error establishing a database connection"

Comment: Revisa que la información de nombre de base de datos, usuario, password y host sean correctos en el wp-config